# Comparing two Excel Sheets in same XLS Document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare between Excel worksheets](https://superuser.com/questions/89044/compare-between-excel-worksheets)

The title actually explains it all.

I would like to be able to compare two Excel Sheets in one Excel document.

Comparing two different files can be accomplished by going to the "View Tab" and clicking Arrange All / Split.

But how can I compare two excel sheets in the same document?

Help is very appreciated!

Thanks SuperUsers ;p

Comment: Some of the options in this answer might work for you: http://superuser.com/questions/18626/how-do-i-compare-two-excel-documents

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is possible but as a quick and dirty fix you could do a right click copy sheet to a new excel file and do the comparison against that.

Comment: But then it's a source of mistakes with the copy/edition/copy back : easy to lose cells in the process.

Comment: I think this is a good scheme if you cannot compare two sheets within a XLS. The entire sheet will get copied out to another XLS -- this is not a cut-and-paste operation and I doubt if you will loose any cells.

Comment: If you wanted to be sure you were working on the right version you could move the sheet instead then move it back when you're done with your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the same workbook twice, the second time as Read-Only.  Then you can compare them side-by-side on the screen, just like two different workbooks.

This way, you will never lose data due to copy-and-paste errors, or forgetting to put any changes back in the proper workbook.